# What is the most efficient way to keep writing a frequently changing JavaScript object to a file in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, file, filesystems

I have a JavaScript object with many different properties, and it might look something like this:

```
var myObj = {
    prop1: "val1",
    prop2: [...],
    ...
}
```

The values in this object keep updating very frequently (several times every second) and there could be thousands of them. New values could be added, existing ones could be changed or removed.

I want to have a file that always has the updated version of this object. The simple approach for doing this would be just writing the entire object to the file all over again after each time that it changes like so:

`fs.writeFileSync("file.json", JSON.stringify(myObj));`

This doesn't seem very efficient for big objects that need to be written very frequently. Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Can I ask for what reason do you write it to a file so often ?

Comment: I'd like to write the updated data to the file as often as possible, so that at any point the file would have the latest state of the object, and for example in the case of an application crash the minimal amount of data would be lost. Of course, if it's not really practical, then I'll have to find another way but that's what this question is for; to know if there is an efficient way.

Comment: Why do you need the current value to always be in a file?  Perhaps that's the better problem to solve because nothing that rewrites a file several times a second will ever be particularly efficient.  And, certainly `fs.writeFileSync()` is probably the worst way to do it as synchronous file operations block other node.js activity.

Comment: For efficiency, avoid writing it to disk multiple time a second.  For example, provide a simple http API that returns the current object and let the process that wants the current value get it via HTTP so you never have to write it out to a file at all.  This saves not only the disk activity, but all the unnecessary calls to `JSON.stringify()` too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maintaining a file (on the filesystem) containing the current state of a rapidly changing object is surprisingly difficult. Specifically, setting things up so some other program can *read* the file at any time is the hard part.  Why? At any time the file may be in the process of being written, so the reader can get inconsistent results.

Here's an outline of a good way to do this.

1) write the file less often than each time the state changes. Whenever the state changes call `updateFile (myObj)`. It sets a timer for, let's say, 500ms, then writes the very latest state to the file when the timer expires. Something like this: not debugged:

```
    let latestObj
    let updateFileTimer = 0
    function updateFile (myObj) {
      latestObj = myObj
      if (updateFileTimer === 0) {
         updateFileTimer = setTimeout (
           function () {
             /* write latestObj to the file */
             updateFileTimer = 0
           }, 500)
      }
    }
```

This writes the latest state of your object to the file, but no more than every 500ms.

Inside that timeout function, write out a temporary file. When it's written delete the existing file and rename the temp file to have the existing file's name. Do all this asynchronously so the rest of your program won't have to wait for the filesystem to work. Your timeout function will look like this

```
         updateFileTimer = setTimeout (
           function () {
             /* write latestObj to the file */
             fs.writeFile("file.json.tmp", 
                           JSON.stringify(myObj), 
                           function (err) {
                             if (err) throw err;  
                             fs.unlink ( "file.json", 
                                        function (err) {
                                          if (!err)
                                            fs.renameSync( "file.json.tmp", "file.json")
                                        } )
                           } )
             updateFileTimer = 0
           }, 500)
```

There's one more thing to worry about. There's a brief period of time between the `unlink` and the `renameSync` operation where the "file.json" file does not exist in the file system. So, any program you write that READs "file.json" needs to try again if the file isn't found.

If you use a Linux, MacOs, FreeBSD, or other UNIX-derived operating system for this code it will work well.  Those operating systems' file systems allow one program to unlink a file while another program is reading it. If you're running it on a DOS-derived operating system like Windows, the unlink operation will fail when another program is reading the  file.

Answer (score 3):

You should use a database. Something simple like sqlite3 would be a good option. Have a table with just two columns 'Key' 'Value' and use it as a key value store.  You will gain advantages like transactions and better performance than a file as well as simplifying your access.